# How to save radio button values to cookies in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies

I would post code showing exactly what I’m trying to accomplish but apparently that just starts arguments. So can anyone post the JavaScript syntax to save 2 different radio buttons from an HTML form into the browsers cookies? I cannot use JQuery, it has to be done with JavaScript.

Comment: post your code first, worry about arguments later

Comment: I already did. Check out the cool arguments with the 0 help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214000/javascript-how-to-save-gender-form-radio-buttons-to-browser-cookies

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214000/javascript-how-to-save-gender-form-radio-buttons-to-browser-cookies

add this function to your page

```
 function GetGenderValue() {
  var genderRadio = document.getElementsByName('Gender');
  var genderValue;
  for(var i = 0; i < genderRadio.length; i++){
      if(genderRadio[i].checked){
          genderValue = genderRadio[i].value;
      }
  }
  return genderValue;

 }
```

then in your other function named *SaveForm()*, add this line:

```
setCookie("Gender", GetGenderValue());
```

to load the values add another function:

```
function SetGenderValue(genderValue) {
  var genderRadio = document.getElementsByName('Gender');
  for(var i = 0; i < genderRadio.length; i++){
      if(genderRadio[i].value == genderValue){
          genderRadio[i].checked = true;
      }
  }
}
```

and update your *LoadForm()*, add

```
SetGenderValue( getCookie("Gender") );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I still cant get it to load into the correct field.

Answer (score 0):

I am a noob too, however `setCookie` is php not javascript.

`document.cookie= "cookiename" = "cookievalue";` should be right.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie